# Recovering a terminal object from categorical definition of limit

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

**Question:** I want to define terminal objects from the categorical definition of limit, but I cannot. What is my mistake in the following argument?

**Limit:** Given a functor $F: \mathcal{D} \longrightarrow \mathcal{C}$, a limit of $F$ is a cone $L$ such that for every $M$, these following sets are naturally isomorphic $$\mathcal{C}(M, L) \cong \textbf{Nat}(\Delta_M, F)$$
($\Delta_M$ is the constant functor and Nat is the set of natural transformation between these two functors $\Delta_M, F$)

**Recovery of terminal object:** Let the category $\mathcal{D}=\emptyset$ be the empty category,  and $F=\Delta_{L}$.  Then, for every $M$, $$\mathcal{C}(M, L) \cong \textbf{Nat}(\Delta_M, \Delta_{L})$$
$\Delta_L$ assignes $L$ to the empty category. So this isomorphy is trivial because both sets are the same. But it does not say $\mathcal{C}(M, L) $ has only one element, or $M \longrightarrow L$ is unique.

Where is my mistake?

**Notice:** The question here is regarding the categorical definition of limit and I am not asking for an explanation, I am looking for my mistake in my argument. (Response to a possible duplicate of other questions! )

Comment: What's $\Delta_M$ in the context $D=\emptyset$ ? And thus, what is $Nat(\Delta_M,\Delta_\emptyset)$ ?

Comment: Edited and Added definitions.

Comment: No that was not the point of my question, my question was actually to hint you at a solution

Comment: This has been asked before, multiple times, including [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2544949/explanation-of-terminal-objects-using-limits).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explanation of terminal objects using limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2544949/explanation-of-terminal-objects-using-limits)

Comment: @Malice The question there is not about the categorical definition, the approach is different as I mentioned explicitly I am asking about the categorical definition.

Comment: @Max thanks! I do not get it though, can you elaborate a bit more? (I change the name of $\Delta_{\emptyset}$ to $\Delta_{L}$ in the question. )

Comment: They're not different questions, and in particular Clive's answer is exactly an answer to your question.

Comment: @Max Thanks I got it, you mean $\Delta_{\emptyset}$ is unique so $\Delta_{\emptyset}=\Delta_{M}$. 
My mistake was that I assumed $\Delta_{\emptyset}$ assigns $L$ to the empty category! Other parts now are clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "$\Delta_L$ assigns $L$ to the empty category".

For any set $S$, there is a unique function $\varnothing \to S$. Using this function where appropriate, you can see:

- There is a unique functor $E : \varnothing \to \mathcal{C}$
- There is a unique natural transformation $\epsilon : E \to E$.

Consequently, $\textbf{Nat}(\Delta_M, \Delta_{L})$ is the one point set $\{ \epsilon \}$.

Comment: That was my mistake. I did not notice that empty functor does not assign any objects or morphisms to the empty category. Its image is also empty.