# Terminal object as a limit

Tags: category-theory

$n$-lab says that that a limit (resp colimit) over the [empty diagram](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/empty+diagram) in a category $\mathcal{C}$ is the terminal (resp initial) object of $\mathcal{C}$.

Is this true because if we are to give a morphism to each object in the empty diagram, we must factor through the limit over the empty diagram - where each object vacuuously has a morphism to the objects of the empty diagram, and hence necessarily has a unique morphism to this limit.

Comment: It seems you do not need the empty category in your question. You should also formulate more precisely: If the empty diagram has a limit, then the limit is a terminal object (no morphisms are required because the diagram is empty), and conversely if a terminal object exists, then the empty diagram has a limit.

Comment: @PaulFrost The empty diagram is just the image of the empty category under some functor to $\mathcal{C}$ right? (it's true it was unnecessary to denote it at all though I guess)

Comment: You are right, a diagram in $\mathcal{C}$ is a functor from a small category $I$ to $\mathcal{C}$. But I believe that is clear what the empty diagram is without explicitly defining  the empty category ;-)

Comment: @PaulFrost Sure :)

Comment: $\mathsf{Hom}(-,\prod_{s\in S}A_s)\cong\prod_{s\in S}\mathsf{Hom}(-,A_s)$ assuming $S$-fold products exist in the category. The product on the right is in $\mathbf{Set}$. Now, if $S$ is empty...

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1991522/terminal-objects-as-nullary-products

Answer (score 2):

I only consider the limit case (colimits are dual).

The limit of a diagram $\Delta$ is a cone over $\Delta$ with a certain universal property (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(category_theory).

A cone over the empty diagram $\Delta_\emptyset$ is nothing else than an object $X$ of $\mathcal{C}$, and the universal property says that $X$ is a limit of $\Delta_\emptyset$ if and only if each object $Y$ admits a unique morphism $Y \to X$.

Comment: This is maybe a bad question, because it violates the principle of equivalence, but are cones over the empty diagram "_really_" objects of the original category? Or is it just that the natural isomorphism between the original category and the category of cones of the empty diagram over the original category is too trivial to ever bother stating explicitly? (Trivial enough to be worth defining them as equal, although again that's an "evil" question http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence )

Comment: @hasManyStupidQuestions A cone over a diagram is a pair consisting of an object $X$ and an indexed family of morphisms with a certain property. Thus also a cone over the empty diagram is still such a pair (having an empty family of morphisms). Hence it is not an object and you are right : There is an obvious natural isomorphism between the original category and the category of cones of the empty diagram, but the categories are technically different. Anyway, in my opinion it would be nitpicking to worry about this point.

Answer (score 2):

Given a small category $J$, a category $\mathcal C$ admits all limits of shape $J$ whenever the "constant diagram" functor
$$ \mathcal C \to \mathcal C^J,\quad X\mapsto \{j \mapsto X, (i\overset f \to j) \mapsto \mathrm{id}_X\} $$
admits a right adjoint. When $J=\varnothing$, then $\mathcal C^J = 1$ (the terminal category). But a right adjoint of the unique functor $\mathcal C \to 1$ is precisely the selection of a terminal object in $\mathcal C$.